# Why the static methods values() and valueOf() in Enum are added by the compiler and not explicitly declared in the Enum class?

Tags: java, enums, language-design

In reading through the Javadoc of `Enum` I can see a [signature of `valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) that is not what I usually use. Also the javadoc for values() method is also missing. I read that these methods are actually generated by the compiler automatically. So my question is why are these methods not declared as static methods in the `Enum` class itself? What is the need for the methods to be included like the way they are by the compiler? Why this extra layer of abstraction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These methods have to be declared not in `Enum`, but in the `Enum` subclass, the `enum` type you're writing.  They can't be added any other way, not least since static methods don't inherit the way instance methods do.

Comment: Can you elaborate your last sentence ie "not least since static methods don't inherit the way instance methods do." part of it?

Comment: For starters, a static method like `Enum.values()` could not take into account which subclass of `Enum` it was being called on, so `Foo.values()` and `Bar.values()` couldn't do different things.