# Why is the values()-method in an enum static and implicit, and not defined as native?

Tags: java

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452703/why-the-static-methods-values-and-valueof-in-enum-are-added-by-the-compiler) one, but I'm not satisfied with its answer.
Why is the values()-method of every enum in Java implicit and static? Couldn't it just be defined as:

```
public final native T[] values();
```

I have an interface that is exclusively implemented by enums, but because the implicit method is static, i can't even define values() in that interface.

Comment: `native` is an implementation detail - it just means a method is not implemented in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be `static`: Because... that's the point of the method. Given an enum *type*, let's say `CardSuit`, you'd want to invoke `CardSuit.values()`, not `CardSuit.SPADES.values()`, that makes no sense.

It cannot be `native`: `native`, specifically, means: "The actual code for this method is defined in C" (or at any rate, in a natively compiled file that has been `.loadLibrary`ied in, or has been auto-loaded in by the JVM itself). The implementation of the `values()` method isn't done 'in C'.

> I have an interface that is exclusively implemented by enums, but because the implicit method is static, i can't even define values() in that interface.

Static methods don't 'do' inheritance. They live outside of it. It makes the most sense to think of static methods as not participating in the type system at all; they must be written inside types *only* because java's namespacing system piggybacks on the type system. They cannot be inherited, you can't override them. The definition of `final` on a `static` method is daft (a holdover from the Java 1.0 specs that aren't worth fixing at this point).

Why do you think the much-derided concept of the `Factory` exists? That's taking the 'class' concept and making a separate type hierarchy for that concept, so that you can have an instance that represents the class: You have, say, a `Person` class, as well as a `PersonFactory` class. An *instance* of `PersonFactory` is a lot like the concept `Person.class`, except `Person.class` cannot 'do' inheritance, and static methods cannot be interfaced or overridden in any way. Whereas with the factory stuff, the actual factory *is* an instance, thus the relevant methods *can be* instance methods, and thus you can have em implement interfaces and the like.

At any rate, given that `values()` is static and doesn't make sense as non-static, defining an interface that your enums are meant to implement just does not make sense. At best, the factory equivalent for your enums could implement it: `values()` is a question you ask of the entire type itself. Which **is not** what interface methods are for! Interface methods are questions you can ask **of a specific instance of the type**.

Answer (score 2):

Say you defined `enum MyEnum`.

That must be static, because you want to access all values with `MyEnum.values()`.

And as `values()` must be static it cannot use the generic parameter (`enum MyEnum extends Enum<MyEnum>`).

So don't define an interface for your enums with a method named `values`. Find another appropriate name.

Comment: Why does it have to be implicit tho?

Comment: To add more why it needs to be `static`: it is because enum types are not required to have any values, so they can be empty like `enum MyEnum{}`. Now if `values()` would not be `static`, it would mean they are *instance* methods, so we could only call it on *instance* of enum. But `MyEnum` doesn't have such instance/value, so we wouldn't be able to obtain information that it is "empty".

Comment: @xtay2 Note that `T[] values()` is not valid because generic type doesn't exist in *static* context and `values()` need to be `static` (as already explained). Also note that there is no *self* type mechanism in Java, so we can't write something like `public static native self[] values();` to let `self` represent current type which declares or *inherits* this code. So we can only pick some *specific* type. That leaves us with only `Enum`. But `Enum[] values()` is not as useful as `SpecificEnum[] values()`, so it is better to let compiler generate that for us in each enum type.

Comment: @Pshemo wasn't it what I said? *And as values() must be static it cannot use the generic parameter*

Comment: @xtay2 because you can't write the prototype for it.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès "*wasn't it what I said?*" it was. My comment wasn't meant as *correction* of your answer, but as clarification for OP who probably missed it.